# common effect sizes in psychological research and calculation/ transformation

Tags: r, correlation, meta-analysis, effect-size, cohens-d

I am working on an empirical literature analysis.
For that I have to code some variables in a specific manner (analysis includes 150 published studies in the field of behavior Neuroscience, educational Psychology and social Psychology).

My hypothesis is that sample size behaves inversely proportional to effect size. (replication of Kühberger et al., 2014).

I thought of transforming effect sizes into r (or is cohen's d more useful?)
I probably will just integrate studies with between-subject design in my coding scheme.

It would be great to have one transformed effect size to run a correlation analysis.
What measures do I need to transforme one into another effect size? (SD?, mean? etc).

Could you recommend a book/article which describes calculation and transformation of effect sizes?

Comment: Most books on meta-analysis discuss this sort of issue. You might want to browse posts tagged [tag:meta-analysis] on this site for some ideas.